# issue in datatables with group button in row - angular4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am using `datatables`  plugin in my `angular4` application and I am trying to add `dropdownmenu` but when I click on the button it is not showing up

[image: DataTable with Group button Menu ...]

As showed in above if I click on edit button of any row it's not displaying any drop down menu, I also tried adding single button and called `editRow()` but it didn't call the method, where as when I click on edit button which is outside the `datatable` it showed the menu.

Here is how I am adding edit button in my component ...

```
options = {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
        callback({
            aaData: data
        })
        })
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "product" },
        { data: "dept" },
        {  mRender : function(data, type, row) {
            return '<div class="btn-group dropdown" dropdown>'+
            '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle txt-color-magenta"  dropdownToggle>'+
            '<i class="fa fa-gear fa-lg"></i>'+
            '<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>'+
            '</button>'+
            '<ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">'+
            '<li> <a (click)="editRow("'+data+')">Action</a> </li>'+
            '<li><a (click)="callMeTwo()">Another action</a></li>'+
            '<li><a (click)="callMeThree()">Something else here</a></li>'+
            '<li class="divider"></li><li><a (click)="(null)">Separated link</a></li>'+
            '</ul>'+
            '</div>'
        }
        }
    ],
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']
};
```

As per datatables forums found [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29723/add-custom-buttons-to-row-when-also-defining-columns) or [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) if I add like below ...

```
options = {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
        callback({
            aaData: data
        })
        })
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "product" },
        { data: "dept" },
        { defaultContent: '<ul class="demo-btns"> <li>' +
        '<a (click)="callMeOne()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> </a>'+
        '</li>' },
    ],
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']
};
```

getting `Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null` error, Please help me in how to get it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and finally made it work ... just has to add `data-toggle` in `<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle txt-color-magenta"  data-toggle="dropdown">` but now the `click` function is not working in anchor tag `<li> <a (click)="editRow(row)" class="btn btn-success">Action</a> </li>` when I click on Action it suppose to call `editRow` function but it didn't.
Also I am not able to figure it out how to call a function say `RowSelected` when I select a row.